# UITextView : get text with wrap info

Tags: ios, uitextview

Is it possible to get the text inside a UITextView with its wrap info.

[image]

So in this case. I will get text like "Dear StackOverFlow,\n\nYou make my..." with no more "\n". I would like to get a newline after "and now I", like shown in the UITextView.

Comment: For an iOS 7 version of this question, see [How do I get word wrap information with the new iOS 7 APIs?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19600372/35690)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See my answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13588322/341994

What you are asking to do is exactly what Core Text does for you. Indeed, Core Text is *how* UITextView knows how to wrap text. So you can ask Core Text where the line breaks are, just as UITextView does. See the example code in my answer - it's a lot simpler and more reliable than what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hey thanks, this is definitely a more straight forward solution.

Answer (score -1):

**Edit :**
Matt's answer above provides a more straight forward way of doing this.

Ok it seems this is not possible. I had to do it manually.

This may not be very accurate and I am still testing for bugs.

```
- (NSString*) wrappedStringForString: (NSString*)rawString {
NSString *resultSring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""];

float textViewWidth = 130; //Width of the UITextView

//Check if already small.
CGSize textSize = [rawString sizeWithFont:self.backMessageTextView.font];
float textWidth = textSize.width;
if (textWidth < textViewWidth) {
    return rawString;
}

//Loop
NSUInteger length = [rawString length];
unichar buffer[length];
[rawString getCharacters:buffer range:NSMakeRange(0, length)];

NSString *singleLine = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""];
NSString *word = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""];
NSString *longWord = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""];

float difference;
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < length; i++) {

    unichar character = buffer[i];

    //Add to word
    if (character != '\n') {
        word = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%c", word, character];
    }

    if (character == '\n') {
        float wordLength = [word sizeWithFont:self.backMessageTextView.font].width;
        float lineLength = [singleLine sizeWithFont:self.backMessageTextView.font].width;
        if ((lineLength + wordLength) > textViewWidth) {
            resultSring = [resultSring stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@\n", singleLine];
            singleLine = @"";
            singleLine = [singleLine stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@\n",word];
            word = @"";
        } else {
            singleLine = [singleLine stringByAppendingString: word];
            word = @"";
            resultSring = [resultSring stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@\n", singleLine];
            singleLine = @"";
        }
    } 

    else if (character == ' ') {            
        float wordLength = [word sizeWithFont:self.backMessageTextView.font].width;
        float lineLength = [singleLine sizeWithFont:self.backMessageTextView.font].width;

        if ((lineLength + wordLength) > textViewWidth) {
            if (wordLength > textWidth) {
                resultSring = [resultSring stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@\n", singleLine];
                singleLine = @"";
                int j = 0;
                for (; j < [word length]; j++) {
                    unichar longChar = [word characterAtIndex:j];
                    longWord = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%c", longWord, longChar];
                    float longwordLength = [longWord sizeWithFont:self.backMessageTextView.font].width;
                    float longlineLength = [singleLine sizeWithFont:self.backMessageTextView.font].width;
                    if ((longlineLength + longwordLength) >= textViewWidth) {
                        singleLine = [singleLine stringByAppendingString:longWord];
                        word = @"";
                        longWord = @"";                            
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
            resultSring = [resultSring stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@\n", singleLine];
            singleLine = @"";
        }          
        singleLine = [singleLine stringByAppendingString: word];
        word = @"";
    }        
}

float wordLength = [word sizeWithFont:self.backMessageTextView.font].width;
float lineLength = [singleLine sizeWithFont:self.backMessageTextView.font].width;
// handle any extra chars in current word
if (wordLength > 0) {
    if ((lineLength + wordLength) > textViewWidth) {
        resultSring = [resultSring stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@\n", singleLine];
        singleLine = @"";
    }
    singleLine = [singleLine stringByAppendingString:word];
}

// handle extra line
if (lineLength > 0) {
    resultSring = [resultSring stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@\n", singleLine];
}
return resultSring;
}
```

Comment: You might gain something from looking at matt's answer above.

Comment: wow i wonder if i really deserved the down vote for trying something that worked.